# Text overlay on ffmpeg live stream rtmp output

Tags: ffmpeg

I have ffmpeg take an HLS stream and output into an rtmp url with this command.

ffmpeg -re -i "http://184.72.239.149/vod/smil:BigBuckBunny.smil/playlist.m3u8" -acodec libmp3lame -ar 44100 -b:a 128k -pix_fmt yuv420p -profile:v baseline -s 426x240 -bufsize 6000k -vb 400k -maxrate 1500k -deinterlace -vcodec libx264 -preset veryfast -g 30 -r 30 -f flv "rtmp://ingest-us-east.a.switchboard.zone/live/moo-abced-ppoo-noas"

I would like to put text overlay on the stream but I can't figure out how to do it. I need to have the the ability to control when the text comes up on the screen. Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: Do you need to overlay text at arbitrary times or do you have a set timeline of when to overlay the text?

Comment: At arbitrary times